# postgresql - center - "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Tags: postgresql, postgis

On Slackware 14.0 x86_64 with postgresql-9.2.4 and postgis-2.0.3.
Have loaded essex-latest.osm.pbf into a database.

I want to get the centre of the roads in Essex, but am having problems.
These work OK:

```
SELECT st_Extent(way), st_area(st_Extent(way)) from planet_osm_roads;    
       st_extent                    |     st_area          
------------------------------------------------+------------------
 BOX(-10979.62 6693910.54,144349.79 6822695.15) | 20004037488.3802



SELECT center(box '((-10979.62, 6693910.54),(144349.79, 6822695.15))');
         center          
-------------------------
 (66685.085,6758302.845)
```

(But I have wondered why the function is center and not st_center).

Anyway, so why doesn't this work:

```
SELECT center(st_Extent(way)) from planet_osm_roads;
ERROR:  function center(box2d) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT center(st_Extent(way)) from planet_osm_roads;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Function center gets argument of type box, not box2d that st_Extent returns. With [ST_Centroid](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html) you doesn't need to call st_Extent even, try ST_Centroid(way)

Answer (score 1):

`center` is not a PostGIS function, it is a [core geometry function for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html).

The best way to find the midpoint of a linestring is to use a [linear referencing function](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Linear_Referencing) (e.g., `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point()` or `ST_LineInterpolatePoint()` for PostGIS >=2.1).

See also [`ST_PointOnSurface`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_PointOnSurface.html).